# How to open txt files created during ios application debug on ios devices

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging

I am developing an iPad app with Xcode 4.6. In order to collect some critical information about the app, during the debug process (for real ios device) I put some data in a text file, and an example can be demonstrated with the following code:

```
   std::ofstream f;
    f.open("test.txt",std::ios::out ) ;
    for (int i=0;i<100;i++)
    {
        f << i << std::endl;
    }
    f.close() ;
```

After running the app, I want to examine the data in `test.txt`, however, I do not know how I can find it. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121613/browse-the-files-created-on-a-device-by-the-ios-application-im-developing-on-w) seems to be helpful, but I cannot find the `Application Data` following his instruction.

Comment: Why don't you develop a proper logging class and use it throughout the lifetime of your app?

Comment: @trojanfoe thanks for your comments, and it is a little complicated in my case. The data I collected will be treated as an input of another software package, and I will analyse the data then.

Comment: Are you doing this on a real iOS device or the simulator? How you access the file depends on the answer.

Comment: @rmaddy I works on a real iOS device.

Comment: What part of the instructions in your linked post don't you understand? Once you save the files, dig into the saved file for the desired sandbox files.

Answer (score 1):

Application Documents folder is accessible via iTunes. But for that you must enable File sharing for application. Here is a link for enabling file sharing https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/iPhoneOSTechOverview/CoreServicesLayer/CoreServicesLayer.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007898-CH10-SW30

but better use NSLogs or any other custom Logger.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to set the full path to the output file as by default the *current working directory* will be the app bundle directory, which you cannot write to (you aren't specifying a full path in your file open statement, so it will use the *cwd*).

So, if you want it to appear in the app's documents directory you'll need to get that using Objective-C (or Objective-C++) and pass that path to the C++ method you posted.

I would recommend using Objective-C++ to allow you to mix programming languages (change file extension to `.mm`):

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
std::string docDir = [paths[0] UTF8String];
std::ofstream f;
f.open(docDir + "/test.txt", std::ios::out);
for (int i=0;i<100;i++)
{
    f << i << std::endl;
}
f.close();
```