# Swift - Redirect Console Log To Document Folder

Tags: ios, objective-c, logging, console, swift2

I'm looking for the **Swift equivalent** of the following **Objective C** common code. 
In Objective C we had the following to redirect logging to the document folder instead of to the console:

```
- (void) redirectConsoleLogToDocumentFolder
{
 NSArray *paths = 
NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,
YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *logPath = [documentsDirectory
stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"console.log"];
freopen([logPath 
cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding],"a+",stderr);
}
```

**How is that done in Swift 2 ?**

Comment: do you need conversion for whole code or just for the line freopen ?

Comment: The whole code, if you don't mind!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I suggest to read about logging in [swift](http://ericasadun.com/2015/05/22/swift-logging/)

```
func redirectConsoleLogToDocumentFolder() {
    var paths: NSArray = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
    var documentsDirectory: NSString = paths[0]
    var logPath: NSString = documentsDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent("console.log")
    var cstr = (logPath as NSString).UTF8String
    freopen(cstr, "a+", stderr)
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It's throwing errors but at least I have what to work with now. The 3 errors are that both NSDocumentDirectory and NSDomainMask are 'unresolved identifiers', and 'stringByAppendingPathComponent' is unavailable: Use URLByAppendingPathComponent on NSURL instead.

Comment: @Mt.T I am using the code you provided to redirect stdout to a file. When I do so I observe that print() no longer comes to the console (good) and that there is a file associated with my app that I can access via iTunes (good). BUT, the size of the file is 0. Any thoughts?

Comment: @TejaNandamuri, I am not getting any text into a log file.

Comment: works like a charm, I had to modify this `let documentsDirectory: NSString = paths[0] as! NSString`
You can access such log file from mac using https://stackoverflow.com/a/26379551/5414535

Answer (score 8):

An updated answer for Swift 3.0

```
if let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first {
    let documentsDirectory = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)
    let logPath = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("console.log")!
    freopen(logPath.absoluteString, "a+", stderr)
}
```