# How to access data from third party app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, directory

I am trying to develop an ipad app that records the data from a stylus pen into a file which I can then extract to a computer for analysis.

In the app, I have a button that when pressed stores the accelerometer values of the stylus into a NSmutablearray (using startAccelerationUpdate method below) and then after a defined duration I write to a file (using endUpdates method)

```
- (IBAction)startWrittingBtn:(id)sender {

    _writeTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.1 target:self selector:@selector(startAccelerationUpdates) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10 target:self selector:@selector(endUpdates) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}

-(void) startAccelerationUpdates
{
    self.motionManager = [JotStylusManager sharedInstance].jotStylusMotionManager;
    self.motionManager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = .1;

    // Update accelerometer
    if (self.motionManager.accelerometerAvailable) {
        NSString *strAccel = [self stringFromAccel: self.motionManager.accelerometerData.acceleration];
        NSString *strTime = [self stringFromTimeInterval: self.motionManager.accelerometerData.timestamp];
        NSString *strPressure = [_pressure_lb.text substringFromIndex:13];
        [self.accel_val_label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",@"Accel val:",strAccel]];
        [self.time_stamp setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",@"Time:",strTime]];

        [_stylusDataArray addObject: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@,%@", strTime, strPressure, strAccel]];
        }
}

-(void)endUpdates
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *fileName  = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"dataFile.plist"];
    [_stylusDataArray writeToFile:fileName atomically:YES];
    [_writeTimer invalidate];
    NSLog(fileName);
    NSLog(@"Ended");
}
```

Using NSLog I can see that the file is supposedly at  /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/9D2B817D-5F0F-4121-9102-84346C6AAD7F/Documents/dataFile.plist however I don't know how to access it using iExplorer (or any other tools)

Do I have to jailbreak the ipad to do so? or is there another way to get this file?

Any advice/suggestions are welcome, thank you.

Comment: Hey would this help ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121613/browse-the-files-created-on-a-device-by-the-ios-application-im-developing-on-w

Comment: Thank you for the reply, however I tried that already but for some reason my data file  was not in the app content area. Which is what prompted the question :(