# How can I access my app's temp files with Xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c

On iOS, I save a file in /tmp, using `NSTemporaryDirectory()`. Can I access it with Xcode to see what was there ?

Note: Im not looking for NSLog for various reasons, I want to save to a file and retrieve this file with Xcode or some other tool, for debug. I don't care so much if the file is in /tmp or in another directory.

Comment: you can save your file in mainbundle and write on it and you can retrive that file from code or xcode because its in your project. @Thomas

Comment: You can download all of the files written by your app through Xcode by downloading the container: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121613/browse-the-files-created-on-a-device-by-the-ios-application-im-developing-on-w

Comment: thanks, I couldn't find it with google