# Where is CoreData located?

Tags: xcode, macos, core-data

I am writing an app which uses CoreData using `NSPersistentContainer` to save data.

While I am developing the app, I would like to:

- examine the data directly
- back up the data
- see what happens when I change the bundle id

I assume the data is physically stored somewhere, but I’m not sure where to look.

Comment: Are you using [NSPersistentContainer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nspersistentcontainer) ?

Comment: @gcharita Good question. Yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default [NSPersistentContainer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nspersistentcontainer) stores the database inside app container under directory `Libray/Application Support`

[image]

To locate the full path, in simulator, you can print the `applicationSupportDirectory` using `urls(for:in:)` function of the default `FileManager`:

```
print(FileManager.default.urls(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first?.path ?? "nil")
```

If you are running your app on an actual device you can download the application container following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6121649/6791677) answer.

For sandboxed apps the location goes like this:

```
~/Library/Containers/…/Data/Library/Application Support/…
```

Comment: Does it make any difference if the application is sandboxed? I can’t find the file in that location.

Comment: Are you running the app in simulator or on an device?

Comment: On the device itself.

Comment: @Manngo you can follow the steps that you can find in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6121649/6791677) answer to download the application container from the device.

Comment: OK, I found it in `~/Library/Containers/…/Data/Library/Application Support/…`. If you would like to add that for sandboxed apps, I can happily accept your answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Manngo I updated my answer. [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)